# PG-POOL settings issue

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I have pgpool installed on my server but I am facing issue while optimising it. I have 2 different queries running on the same table-

- 1st is update query which runs every 1 min and query exec time is around 30 secs. So technically it is running every 30 secs.
- 2nd is select query.

The issue I am facing here is that update query is running and i try to run select query , my pg-pool process only update query and until unless update query is not finished it wont process my select query.
As of now, I am following the pg-pool default settings.
Any kind of feedback will be helpful:

Comment: *Show your code* please.

Comment: code ...? Do you want me list down the queries ?

Comment: Yes. Edit the question (see "edit" below the tags) and add the queries, then comment here when done. You should also take a look at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring